# fullcalendar firstHour option after initialization

Tags: fullcalendar

do you know if it is possible to set firstHour option after initialization.

I tried : $('#calendar').fullcalendar('options', 'firstHour', 10);
But it does'nt work.

Why do I need this :
I have an html file to create events, I would like the calendar to scroll to the the hour the user have selected/submitted.

regards

Comment: Which version of FullCalendar are you using?

Comment: I am using FullCalendar version 1.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrollTime](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/scrollTime/) to determine how far down the scroll pane is initially scrolled down.

```
scrollTime: '10:00:00',
```

Comment: scrollTime is not supporting since I am using fullcalendar version 1.x. I can't update since I have already done some changes in plugin I am using. What do I do now?

Comment: You should probably not have made changes to the library so you could update more easily. Did you try with this syntax? - `firstHour: 6,`

Comment: Yes. I have tried `firstHour` and is working fine when `fullcalendar` is initializing. But I need something more. I need to dynamically make the calendar to a particular time on an event(say `saveEvent`). Is there any option to do so.

Comment: I do not think it is possible without re initialising the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

[Setting options dynamically](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/) like you are trying to do is only supported as of version 2.9.0

I have seen people successfully set options using the following code before the functionality to dynamically set options became available:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.firstHour = 9;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```